# What is the proper way to call proxied method inside concrete class?

Tags: castle-windsor

For instance I have `IRepository`, Implemented by `Repository` with some Interceptors.

Inside the Interceptor I see that `IRepositoryProxy` basetype is `Object` and Not the `Repository`.

For example: I resolve `IRepository` and call `GetFunctionalityPurposes`,
what I want is the call to `GetAllFunctionalityPurposes` to be also cached/proxied.

This does not work since the methods are invoked in `Repository` but not `IRepositoryProxy`.

IRepository

```
FunctionalityPurpose[] GetFunctionalityPurposes();
FunctionalityPurpose[] GetAllFunctionalityPurposes()
```

Repository

```
[Cached("Tender")]
public virtual FunctionalityPurpose[] GetFunctionalityPurposes()
{
    var model = GetAllFunctionalityPurposes()
        .Where(r => !r.IsHidden && !r.GroupId.HasValue);

    return model;
}

[Cached("Tender", "FunctionalityPurpose")]
public virtual FunctionalityPurpose[] GetAllFunctionalityPurposes()
{
    var model = UnitOfWork.GetSet<Model>().Select(f => f.FunctionalityPurpose)
        .Distinct().OrderBy(r => r.Id).ToArray();

    return model;
}
```

Comment: It would be better that you show some code that explains the issue.

Comment: @L-Three Added some code to illustrate the issue

Comment: @PhilDegenhardt yeah, looks like the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've looked into https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/src/Castle.Windsor/Windsor/Proxy/DefaultProxyFactory.cs#L110 and I've done the registration the easy way: `container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly().BasedOn(typeof(IRepositoryBase<,>))
.WithServiceAllInterfaces().WithServiceSelf().LifestyleTransient());`

Note .WithServiceSelf() call, this actually switches class-based proxying